# Link Font Color Problem

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink, styles, targeting

I've been having a problem with the font color of the links on the template I have been working on. Please take a look at the code:

http://www.wendyhenrichs.com/prob/

You'll notice that the color of my header link is the same color as the links on my navigation bar.

How can I seperate these different styles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Edit your main.css file to

```
#header h1 {
    color: #000000;  // <-- your new title color
    font-family: 'News Cycle',arial,serif;
    font-size: 6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #CCCCCC;
}
```

You have all your links under the selector:

```
#nav ul li a, a:link, a:visited {
color: blue;
font-family: 'Smythe',serif;
font-size: 26px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 0;
line-height: 1.2;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #AAAAAA;
text-transform: none;
word-spacing: 0;
}
```

You could also separate the **#nav ul li a** part from the **a:link, a:visited** and assign a color just to the nav links, instead of all links.

Comment: +1 for naming his CSS file. You could have had bonus points for telling them it was on line 14 too :p

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS in both cases use the a:link and a:visited

```
#nav ul li a, a:link, a:visited {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Smythe',serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #AAAAAA;
    text-transform: none;
    word-spacing: 0;
}

#header h1 a, a:link, a:visited {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You can separate them with

```
#nav ul li a, #nav ul li a:link, #nav ul li a:visited { // nav link style ... }
```

and

```
#header h1 a, #header h1 a:link, #header h1 a:visited { // header link style... }
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that you give color in `<a>` tag

```
#nav ul li a, a:link, a:visited {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Smythe',serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #AAAAAA;
    text-transform: none;
    word-spacing: 0;
}
```

for overwrite this above css write

```
#header a h1{
color: yellow;
}
```